# Quadrupoles (double bipoles), empty or black boxes devices with coupled terminals on Circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz, circuits

All the versions of the package seem to miss a simple and basic component of very general circuit descriptions (black box model) like quadrupoles or boxes with a single port (but with two terminals highlighting the electrical nature of the device, not just one, as for the component 'twoport').
I would like to draw something like this, is it possible?
[image]

Comment: They are straight lines.

Comment: @percusse well, also twoport is made up of straight lines only (even fewer), but still is a component

Comment: I always just use a named node and place the leads to the edges using calc.  But creating a shape with leads preattached is easy enough.  Do you want the box to increase in size to fit the text?

Comment: I mean they are geometric shapes already available in every drawing package. You don't need a circuit library for this.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yes, I would like to add text inside and above the box (if possible), but also on the wires. Can you explain me further the details of your strategy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how to use a normal rectangular node:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}% or tikzpicture
\tikzset{quad/.style={draw, thick, minimum height=.8cm, minimum width=.8cm}}
\node[quad] (A) at (0,0) {text};
\draw ($(A.north west)!.5!(A.west)$) to[short,-o] ++(-.2,0)
      ($(A.south west)!.5!(A.west)$) to[short,-o] ++(-.2,0)
      ($(A.north east)!.5!(A.east)$) to[short,-o] ++(.2,0)
      ($(A.south east)!.5!(A.east)$) to[short,-o] ++(.2,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

Here is how to create a new shape with built in leads and 4 new anchor points (in1, in2, out1 and out2).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\makeatletter
% ************************** blackbox *****************************
\ctikzset{quadpoles/blackbox/.is family}
\ctikzset{quadpoles/blackbox/height/.initial=.5}
\ctikzset{quadpoles/blackbox/width/.initial=.5}
\ctikzset{quadpoles/blackbox/sep/.initial=2pt}
\ctikzset{quadpoles/blackbox/lead/.initial=.5}

\pgfdeclareshape{blackbox}{
\anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}    % within the node, (0,0) is the center

\anchor{text}   % this is used to center the text in the node
    {\pgfpoint{-.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox}{-.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox}}

\savedmacro{\resize}{\pgf@circ@res@temp=\ctikzvalof{bipoles/length}% scale
  \pgf@circ@res@temp=0.5\pgf@circ@res@temp
  \pgf@circ@res@right=\ctikzvalof{quadpoles/blackbox/width}\pgf@circ@res@temp
  \pgf@circ@res@step=0.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox
  \advance\pgf@circ@res@step by \ctikzvalof{quadpoles/blackbox/sep}%
  \ifdim\pgf@circ@res@right<\pgf@circ@res@step \pgf@circ@res@right=\pgf@circ@res@step\fi
  \pgf@circ@res@left=-\pgf@circ@res@right
  \pgf@circ@res@up=\ctikzvalof{quadpoles/blackbox/height}\pgf@circ@res@temp
  \pgf@circ@res@step=0.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox
  \advance\pgf@circ@res@step by \ctikzvalof{quadpoles/blackbox/sep}%
  \ifdim\pgf@circ@res@up<\pgf@circ@res@step \pgf@circ@res@up=\pgf@circ@res@step\fi
  \pgf@circ@res@down=-\pgf@circ@res@up
  \pgfstartlinewidth=\pgflinewidth% don't know why this is needed
}

\savedanchor{\northeast}{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
\savedanchor{\southwest}{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}

\anchor{north east}{\northeast}
\anchor{south west}{\southwest}
\anchor{north}{\pgfextracty{\pgf@circ@res@up}{\northeast}\pgfpoint{0cm}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
\anchor{north west}{\pgfextracty{\pgf@circ@res@up}{\northeast}\pgfextractx{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\southwest}\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
\anchor{west}{\pgfextractx{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\sosuthwest}\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{0cm}}
\anchor{south}{\pgfextracty{\pgf@circ@res@down}{\southwest}\pgfpoint{0cm}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
\anchor{south east}{\pgfextracty{\pgf@circ@res@down}{\southwest}\pgfextractx{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\northeast}\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
\anchor{east}{\pgfextractx{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\northeast}\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{0cm}}

\savedanchor{\inone}{%
  \pgf@circ@res@step=-\ctikzvalof{quadpoles/blackbox/lead}\pgf@circ@res@temp
  \advance\pgf@circ@res@step by \pgf@circ@res@left
  \pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@step}{0.5\pgf@circ@res@up}
}
\anchor{in1}{\inone}

\savedanchor{\intwo}{%
  \pgf@circ@res@step=-\ctikzvalof{quadpoles/blackbox/lead}\pgf@circ@res@temp
  \advance\pgf@circ@res@step by \pgf@circ@res@left
  \pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@step}{0.5\pgf@circ@res@down}
}
\anchor{in2}{\intwo}

\savedanchor{\outone}{%
  \pgf@circ@res@step=\ctikzvalof{quadpoles/blackbox/lead}\pgf@circ@res@temp
  \advance\pgf@circ@res@step by \pgf@circ@res@right
  \pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@step}{0.5\pgf@circ@res@up}
}
\anchor{out1}{\outone}

\savedanchor{\outtwo}{%
  \pgf@circ@res@step=\ctikzvalof{quadpoles/blackbox/lead}\pgf@circ@res@temp
  \advance\pgf@circ@res@step by \pgf@circ@res@right
  \pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@step}{0.5\pgf@circ@res@down}
}
\anchor{out2}{\outtwo}

\foregroundpath{% border and leads drawn here
  \pgfextractx{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\northeast}
  \pgfextracty{\pgf@circ@res@up}{\northeast}
    \pgfextractx{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\southwest}
    \pgfextracty{\pgf@circ@res@down}{\southwest}

  \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}%
  \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\southwest}{\northeast}%
  \pgfusepath{draw}%
  \pgfscope
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfstartlinewidth}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\inone}%
    \pgfextracty{\pgf@circ@res@step}{\inone}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@step}}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\intwo}%
    \pgfextracty{\pgf@circ@res@step}{\intwo}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@step}}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\outone}%
    \pgfextracty{\pgf@circ@res@step}{\outone}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@step}}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\outtwo}%
    \pgfextracty{\pgf@circ@res@step}{\outtwo}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@step}}%
    \pgfusepath{draw}%
  \endpgfscope
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}% or tikzpicture
\node[blackbox] (A) at (0,0) {text};
\node[blackbox,anchor=in1] (B) at (A.out1) {more text};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: shape]