# Tikz, Matrix, and elements above

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I'm trying to typeset some quantum circuits. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9767/whats-a-good-package-for-typesetting-quantum-circuits), they provide an example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

% TikZ libraries `calc` needed now to tweak bracket.
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit,decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
% Dirac Kets
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\ensuremath{\left|#1\right\rangle}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
    % `operator' will only be used by Hadamard (H) gates here.
    % `phase' is used for controlled phase gates (dots).
    % `surround' is used for the background box.
    \tikzstyle{operator} = [draw,fill=white,minimum size=1.5em] 
    \tikzstyle{phase} = [draw,fill,shape=circle,minimum size=5pt,inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{surround} = [fill=blue!10,thick,draw=black,rounded corners=2mm]
    %
    \matrix[row sep=0.4cm, column sep=0.8cm] (circuit) {
    % First row.
    \node (q1) {\ket{0}}; &[-0.5cm] 
    \node[operator] (H11) {H}; &
    \node[phase] (P12) {}; &
    \node[phase] (P13) {}; &
    &[-0.3cm]
    \coordinate (end1); \\
    % Second row.
    \node (q2) {\ket{0}}; &
    \node[operator] (H21) {H}; &
    \node[phase] (P22) {}; &
    &
    \node[operator] (H24) {H}; &
    \coordinate (end2);\\
    % Third row.
    \node (q3) {\ket{0}}; &
    \node[operator] (H31) {H}; &
    &
    \node[phase] (P33) {}; &
    \node[operator] (H34) {H}; &
    \coordinate (end3); \\
    };
    % Draw bracket on right with resultant state.
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace},thick]
        ($(circuit.north east)-(0cm,0.3cm)$)
        to node[midway,right] (bracket) {$\displaystyle\frac{\ket{000}+\ket{111}}{\sqrt{2}}$}
        ($(circuit.south east)+(0cm,0.3cm)$);
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        % Draw background box.
        \node[surround] (background) [fit = (q1) (H31) (bracket)] {};
        % Draw lines.
        \draw[thick] (q1) -- (end1)  (q2) -- (end2) (q3) -- (end3) (P12) -- (P22) (P13) -- (P33);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    %
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Whose output is:

[image]

This is very nice, but now I'd like to add a kind of big box that fit several wires like this:

[image]

Do you have any idea how to do that properly ? I tought that I could use some empty nodes, and then put a fit on top of it, but it's not very practical. A syntax like the one of qcircuit would be very nice.

Thank you!

Comment: why not using qcircuit?

Comment: @percusse: Because I'd like to add some squares/text on it, and qcircuit is not made with tikz so it's hard to do... And also because I would like to learn how to use tikz.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357981/quadrupoles-double-bipoles-empty-or-black-boxes-devices-with-coupled-terminal/358031?s=1|1.6502#358031 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199683/how-to-plot-quantum-logical-gates-with-tikz/200194?s=1|1.4387#200194

Answer (score 2):

This is a possible solution using your own code. We keep `phase` nodes (except `P33`) and use them as reference for a new `fit` node which will cover them:

```
\node[fit=(H11.north-|P13.east) (H21.south-|P22.west), 
       operator, inner sep=0pt, label=center:F]{};
```

It's an `operator` kind of node and its contents is added with `label=center:...` option. Node corners are defined to align with north and south borders of neighbour `operators`.

Aside note: Please, read [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

% TikZ libraries `calc` needed now to tweak bracket.
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit,decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
% Dirac Kets
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\ensuremath{\left|#1\right\rangle}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
    % `operator' will only be used by Hadamard (H) gates here.
    % `phase' is used for controlled phase gates (dots).
    % `surround' is used for the background box.
    \tikzstyle{operator} = [draw,fill=white,minimum size=1.5em] 
    \tikzstyle{phase} = [draw,fill,shape=circle,minimum size=5pt,inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{surround} = [fill=blue!10,thick,draw=black,rounded corners=2mm]
    %
    \matrix[row sep=0.4cm, column sep=0.8cm] (circuit) {
    % First row.
    \node (q1) {\ket{0}}; &[-0.5cm] 
    \node[operator] (H11) {H}; &
    \node[phase] (P12) {}; &
    \node[phase] (P13) {}; &
    &[-0.3cm]
    \coordinate (end1); \\
    % Second row.
    \node (q2) {\ket{0}}; &
    \node[operator] (H21) {H}; &
    \node[phase] (P22) {}; &
    &
    \node[operator] (H24) {H}; &
    \coordinate (end2);\\
    % Third row.
    \node (q3) {\ket{0}}; &
    \node[operator] (H31) {H}; &
    &
%    \node[phase] (P33) {}; 
    &
    \node[operator] (H34) {H}; &
    \coordinate (end3); \\
    };
    % Draw `big box`
    \node[fit=(H11.north-|P13.east) (H21.south-|P22.west), operator, inner sep=0pt, label=center:F]{};
    % Draw bracket on right with resultant state.
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace},thick]
        ($(circuit.north east)-(0cm,0.3cm)$)
        to node[midway,right] (bracket) {$\displaystyle\frac{\ket{000}+\ket{111}}{\sqrt{2}}$}
        ($(circuit.south east)+(0cm,0.3cm)$);
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        % Draw background box.
        \node[surround] (background) [fit = (q1) (H31) (bracket)] {};
        % Draw lines.
        \draw[thick] (q1) -- (end1)  
            (q2) -- (end2) 
            (q3) -- (end3) 
            (P12) -- (P22) 
%           (P13) -- (P33)
            ;
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    %
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

% TikZ libraries `calc` needed now to tweak bracket.
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit,decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
% Dirac Kets
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\ensuremath{\left|#1\right\rangle}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
    % `operator' will only be used by Hadamard (H) gates here.
    % `phase' is used for controlled phase gates (dots).
    % `surround' is used for the background box.
    \tikzstyle{operator} = [draw,fill=white,minimum size=1.5em] 
    \tikzstyle{phase} = [draw,fill,shape=circle,minimum size=5pt,inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{surround} = [fill=blue!10,thick,draw=black,rounded corners=2mm]
    %
    \matrix[row sep=0.4cm, column sep=0.8cm] (circuit) {
        % First row.
        \node (q1) {\ket{0}}; &[-0.5cm] 
        \node[operator] (H11) {H}; &
        \node[] (P12) {}; &
        \node[] (P13) {}; &
        &[-0.3cm]
        \coordinate (end1); \\
        % Second row.
        \node (q2) {\ket{0}}; &
        \node[operator] (H21) {H}; &
        \node[] (P22) {}; &
        &
        \node[operator] (H24) {H}; &
        \coordinate (end2);\\
        % Third row.
        \node (q3) {\ket{0}}; &
        \node[operator] (H31) {H}; &
        &
        \node[] (P33) {}; &
        \node[operator] (H34) {H}; &
        \coordinate (end3); \\
    };
    % Draw bracket on right with resultant state.
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace},thick]
    ($(circuit.north east)-(0cm,0.3cm)$)
    to node[midway,right] (bracket) {$\displaystyle\frac{\ket{000}+\ket{111}}{\sqrt{2}}$}
    ($(circuit.south east)+(0cm,0.3cm)$);

    % to draw the big rectangle 
    \node[fill=white,draw,minimum size=4.3em]at ($(P13)!.5!(P22)$){F};

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    % Draw background box.
    \node[surround] (background) [fit = (q1) (H31) (bracket)] {};
    % Draw lines.
    \draw[thick] (q1) -- (end1)  (q2) -- (end2) (q3) -- (end3) ;
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    %
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have recently produced a tikz library called quantikz that can produce the sort of diagrams you're after. I started from the qcircuit syntax, although it has evolved a little since then. I produced the two circuits described in the question:
[image]
using the code

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzcd}
\lstick{\ket{0}} & \gate{H} & \ctrl{1} & \ctrl{2} & \qw &\rstick[wires=3]{$\displaystyle\frac{\ket{000}+\ket{111}}{\sqrt{2}}$}\qw \\
\lstick{\ket{0}} & \gate{H} & \control{} & \qw & \gate{H} & \qw \\
\lstick{\ket{0}} & \gate{H} & \qw & \control{} & \gate{H} & \qw
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}


\begin{center}
\begin{tikzcd}
\lstick{\ket{0}} & \gate{H} & \gate[wires=2]{F}  & \qw &\rstick[wires=3]{$\displaystyle\frac{\ket{000}+\ket{111}}{\sqrt{2}}$}\qw \\
\lstick{\ket{0}} & \gate{H} & \phantom{wider} & \gate{H} & \qw \\
\lstick{\ket{0}} & \gate{H} & \qw & \gate{H} & \qw
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
```

Of course, you have to have the package installed, and declared in the document preamble. For more details, see the tutorial on the [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.03842). The source code (including the package) can be downloaded by following the "Other formats" link although hopefully, in a day or two, it will be available through ctan.